# Using UUID for file download in a url embed in qr code?

Tags: php, mysql, url, download, uuid

i am new to web development so please pardon me for my lack of knowledge. I have been reading some reference regarding UUID. I know there are several UUID versions(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) with their own pros and cons.

Currently i am trying to build a file download system in my website (i am using Codeigniter 3 and mysql) where the user can scan a qr code on published and printed document generated by my website that contain a url/link that call a download script for login authorization and sending the fileid parameter to locate the file in the database(it specify the row number of the file in tables and check the file actual location), as a simple illustration the url/link looks like this :

```
http://localhost/myweb/download?fileid=2
```

Since this method is guessable where other user can search up other file id by changing the parameter on the url. I intend to create unguessable and unique file parameter. I find that google drive uses something like UUID on the file download url/link though i am not sure if it really is using UUID and which version it uses hence i search up some reference on UUID.

I am not sure what method or which UUID version is best to be use based on my needs while not disregarding the performance(some article said UUID take a lot of storage in db and also takes longer to lookup). Or should i even use UUID for this case?

Currently i am leaning over UUID v1 (i am thinking on using it as a reference column not as a primary key in db tables for filepath location lookup) because it's better on uniqueness aspect(AFAIK) though it's more guessable. UUID v4 is far more unguessable but it's not as unique as UUID v1 (CMIIW) because uniqueness is my main concern since if the url already embed on published qr code i cant change it if there's collision(though it's very highly unlikely and i can create a collision check system before assigning the UUID but it will cost a lot of performance). Please share me your thoughts and help me decide what method is best!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which MySQL version? It sound like an anonymous access where no access control is enforced on the url? How often are they generated. Database can enforce uniqueness containts if uuiv4 is needed. Space and access time  on uuid's seem exaggerated. What is the business impact /likelihood of people brute forcing urls (and gaining approximate time of uuid creation)?

Comment: @danblack I am using MySQL/MariaDB 10.5.16 to be exact. Actually there is authorization system, only people who has account in the website and has session login are allowed to download the file scanned from the url. I am not sure the likelihood but i think it's less likely to happen but possible that someone who gain account access brute forcing urls to download the file he is not supposed to know isn't it? As for the business impact, a confidential document downloaded may be revealed by the unauthorized people.

Comment: if your access control is effective, the disclosure of the URL isn't a problem. Is the exposure of the URL (without its contents) and the user expose anything sensitive (this person is an XYZ partner for example)? Brute forcing the access control is a different problem entirely.

Comment: @danblack the url itself doesnt expose anything sensitive unless the file contained in the url is downloaded and the file is confidential. One of my concern is when people who can pass the authorization system by having account access legally/ilegally but got the qr code/url illegally that contain document he's not supposed to know by brute forcing the url. That's why i thought i need to use uuid in the url download. Is it unnecessary?

Comment: So authorized users don't have a list of files they have access to? I guess its a risk, but understanding the implications of accepting risk on compromised accounts is something that needs management is a business decision and not a technical one.

Comment: Yes they dont have a list of files they have access to, so when they open the url contained in the qr code it just force download the specified file in the url(if they pass the authorization system).. i am sorry i dont quite understand what you mean, so do you mean it's okay for me to use UUID v1 to make unique and relatively-close-to-unguessable download url?

Comment: I feel that aQR-code that contains a URL that contains a UUID will be sufficiently fast and unguessable, etc.  And any flavor of UUID will be nearly as good as any other.